# Can I use a library built with Kotlin coroutines in plain java project?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I am planning to build a library which uses Kotlin coroutines to make the HTTP calls to REST services using retrofit2.
The final output jar will include all the retrofit and Kotlin coroutines dependencies, can we use this final jar in plain java projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can. You may want to have interface adopted to java guidelines, but there is no technical restriction that prevent it.

Answer (score 4):

Your library can internally use coroutines, but you can't expose any `suspend fun`s to the Java client. It is almost impossible to call a `suspend fun` from Java because its signature refers to internal classes.

The recommended way to expose non-blocking Kotlin code to Java is via the `CompletableFuture`, using the [`kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8) module.

Comment: Yes, the plan is to expose only normal public methods which internally launch a coroutine and call the other suspending functions.

Comment: This answer was very helpful. I was facing a `class file for kotlin.coroutines.Continuation not found` in a Java project due to this, exposing a public method in a public interface as suspended.